# Linq: sort items in a collection based on DateTime field

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of Task objects in a list.

```
List<Tasks> tasks = getTasks(); //This populates tasks
```

Each task item has a "dateCreated" field which is a fully fledged DateTime field.

```
Public class Task
{
    DateTime dateCreated {get;set;}
    //other props
}
```

My question is once I have a list of tasks, how can I resort the items in the collection based on this dateCreated field.

1. Best case scenario is if I could resort the existing collection
2. If this isn't possible then using Linq select items based on DateCreated, and populate another collection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement  `IComparable<T>` and use `List<T>.Sort()`.

Or you could:

```
tasks.Sort(t => t.DateCreated);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx

If you don't want to do that, just do:

```
tasks = tasks.OrderBy(t => t.DateCreated).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to implement `IComparable<T>` to sort a list:

```
tasks.Sort((t1,t2) => t1.DateCreated.CompareTo(t2.DateCreated));
```

Answer (score 0):

best way to do that is

```
tasks = tasks.OrderBy(t => t.DateCreated.Ticks).ToList();
```

in this way list will be ordered by date and time